# Python 3.7.0 c.execute(v_sql,[Part_no, Rev_no]) does not recognize my variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to retrieve data from an Oracle DB using Oracle_CX library. However, when I hard code c.execute(v_sql,['02502-9001-12','SS']) it will return me the right data. However, when I have to pass the variable to the function c.execute(v_sql,[Part_No,Rev_no]) does not recognize the values the output is (none)

What I tried to do is passing the values to Part_No and Rev_no 
only when I hard code the data I can receive the right data. I even print before c.execute() is happening to see if the Part_No and Rev_no is printed and it happened. The actual error is that I am not receiving the right data (none) I suppose to receive AAAW07AAFAAF5/PAAq. Looks like the values of def why_(Part_no, Rev_no) do not get populated it to c.execute(v_sql,[Part_No,Rev_no])

c.execute(v_sql,[Part_No,Rev_no])

c.execute(v_sql,['02502-9001-12','SS'])

```
import cx_Oracle
import os




def why__(Part_No, Rev_no):
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('XXXXX', 'XXXX', service_name='XXXXX')
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'XXXX', password='XXXX', dsn=dsn_tns)
    c = conn.cursor()
    #u_sql =('SELECT PART_REV_CFP.GET_OBJKEY(:Part_No,:Rev_no) from dual')
    v_sql =('SELECT PART_REV_CFP.GET_OBJKEY(:Part_No,:Rev_no) from dual')
    print(Part_No)
    print(Rev_no)
    c.execute(v_sql,[Part_No,Rev_no])
    #c.execute(v_sql,['02502-9001-12','SS'])
    R = c.fetchone()
    print('before the loop')
    i=0
    for row in R:
        print('inside the loop')
        i+=1
        print(i)
        print(str(row))
    print('after the loop')
    conn.close()
    return row

Part_No = input("Enter the obs part num: ")
Rev_no = input("Enter the obs part rev: ")
why__(Part_No,Rev_no)
print('outside of the method')
print(why__(Part_No,Rev_no))

OutPut when c.execute(v_sql,[Part_No,Rev_no]) --IN other words no hard coding the values of Part_no and Rev_no



Enter the obsolete part number: 02502-9001-12
Enter the obsolete part revision: ss
before the loop
inside the loop
1
(None,)
after the loop

***Repl Closed***




Output when c.execute(v_sql,['02502-9001-12','SS'])



Enter the obsolete part number: 02502-9001-12
Enter the obsolete part revision: ss
02502-9001-12
ss
before the loop
inside the loop
1
AAAW07AAFAAF5/PAAq
after the loop
outside of the method
02502-9001-12
ss
before the loop
inside the loop
1
AAAW07AAFAAF5/PAAq
after the loop
AAAW07AAFAAF5/PAAq

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: hmm can you check that the type is the same for the hardcoded and variables i.e. type(Part_No) == type('02502-9001-12'). Also your hardcoded example has 'SS' while your input is 'ss'

Comment: It is the same I have the print(Part_no) and print(Rev_no) .. in the output can demonstrate the values

Comment: To debug this can you hardcode the variables part_no and rev_no then insert them into why() e.g. part_no = '02502-9001-12' and rev_no = 'SS'? If this works then it means the issue is what you are inputting and not because you are using variables

Comment: KKAWABAT you were right. I am passing ss and the right variable value is SS